JMeter. Не происходит перенаправление на следующую страницу после авторизации
Я хочу в JMeter реализовать сценарий: юзер заходит на страницу логина, авторизуется (вводит логин и пароль) и заходит на КП сервиса. При отправке запроса авторизации - мы получаем токен, который далее используется для взаимодействия со всем сервисом.
Токен верно извлекается и передается в шаг перехода на КП (я вижу его в request headers). Но возникает другая проблема - после перехода на контрольную панель, вместо ожидаемой страницы я продолжаю видеть страницу авторизации. Сервер возвращает статус код 200,  но содержимое ответа соответствует странице авторизации, а не контрольной панели.
Я проверила куки, настроила хедеры, копалась в настройках, но пока ничего не меняется.

Сравните запросы от JMeter и от браузера при помощи анализатора пакетов типа Fiddler или Wireshark
Запросы должны быть идентичными (кроме динамических параметров вроде вашего токена). Если вы отправите такой же запрос как отправляет браузер - вы перейдете на "КП" (что бы это не значило)
Популярная ошибка: люди забывают Cookies, попробуйте добавить HTTP Cookie Manager
В редких случаях фронтэндщики вместо использования Redirections просто меняют Window.location при помощи JavaScript, если это так то вам нужно будет добавить еще один HTTP Request который открывает "КП" потому что JMeter не умеет исполнять JavaScript
